# Droidcam Ubuntu 18.04 Error

Tags: 18.04, droidcam

When I try to install [DroidCam](https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linuxx/), I get this error:

```
stud:~/Desktop/droidcam-64bit$ ./install  
Webcam parameters: '640' and '480'
Building v4l2loopback-dc.ko
./install: line 36: make: command not found
```

Anyone seen this before?  Any help would be great!

Comment: Seen http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/12/install-droidcam-ubuntu-16-04/ ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete procedure that allowed me to used my android camera with Zoom on ubuntu 20.04. It should also work on 18.04 and with other video software.

You need to install some basic utilities first. Please enter these lines:

```
yes | sudo apt-get install make
yes | sudo apt-get install gcc
yes | sudo apt install adb
yes | sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

Then enter these lines to install. The md5sum must be "OK".

```
cd /tmp
wget https://files.dev47apps.net/linux/droidcam_latest.zip
echo "5ff0e772a76befba4e37e03101b611d7 droidcam_latest.zip" | md5sum -c --
unzip droidcam_latest.zip -d droidcam && cd droidcam
sudo ./install
```

Check the video device was created:

```
lsmod | grep v4l2loopback_dc
```

To run it, start droidcam on your android phone. Start /usr/bin/droidcam on your ubuntu computer and enter the I.P. and port number from your android phone. Only the primary camera is used. The secondary camera and the microphone do not work on Linux.

I connect my phone to power when using it for droidcam and reboot it afterwards.